# When I go from the home page to any page it appears for me "Oops, looks like the page is lost"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

[image]

I published my website in Hostinger and it is working well, but when I go to another page I have a page like shown above. I tried to fix it by changing links but texts but it didn't fix it.
Note "I am Hosting my website in a subdomain"

this is my code

```
//App File

import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Home, AboutPage, ProjectsPage } from "./pages/index";
/**import {
  Hero,
  About,
  Skills,
  Projects,
  Contact,
  Footer,
} from "./sections/index"; */
//import { Navigator } from "./components/index";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
          <Route path="/projects" element={<ProjectsPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
//Navbar component
import "./Navbar.css";
import Logo from "../../assets/images/MegaSiteLogo.png";

const menus = ["Home", "About", "Projects", "Contact us"];

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="navbar navbar-expand-md text-black shadow-sm mb-3">
      <div className="container">
        <a href="/" className="navbar-brand">
          <img src={Logo} alt="logo" width={"120px"} />
        </a>
        <button
          className="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#mainmenu"
        >
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainmenu">
          <ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            {menus.map((menu) => (
              <li className="nav-item" key={menu}>
                <a
                  key={menu}
                  href={
                    menu === "Home"
                      ? "/"
                      : menu === "Contact us"
                      ? "#contact"
                      : menu === "About"
                      ? "/about"
                      : menu === "Projects"
                      ? "/projects"
                      : menu
                  }
                  className="nav-link"
                >
                  {menu}
                </a>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

I tried to change links' texts and search on Youtube and Google but nothing happened and I didn't find anything

Comment: You need to use `<Link/>` not `<a>` with react router, it it won't be able to detect the page change

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `<Link/>` not `<a>` with react router, it it won't be able to detect the page change